# Need to exclude a word (or number of characters) in my code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Module that will format an excel spreadsheet for my team at work. There is one column that will contain the word "CPT" and various CPT codes with descriptions. 
I need to delete all text (CPT description) after the 5 digit CPT code but alsp keep the word CPT in other cells.

For example: Column S, Row 6 contains only the word "CPT"   (not in quotations)
Then Column S, Row 7 contains the text "99217 Observation Care Discharge"

This setup repeats several times throughout Column S.

I would like for Row 6 to stay the same as it is ("CPT") but in Row 7 i only want to keep "99217"

Unfortunately, this is not possible to do by hand as there are several people who will need this macro and our spreadsheets can have this wording repeated hundreds of times in this column with different CPT codes and descriptions.

I have tried various If/Then statements, If/Then/Else

```
Sub CPTcolumn()
Dim celltxt As String
celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("S6" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Text
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("S6" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LR
    If InStr(1, celltxt, "CPT") Then
Next i

Else
    With Range("S6" & i)
    .Value = Left(.Value, InStr(.Value, " "))
End With
Next i

End If
End Sub
```

When i try to run it I get Various "Compile Errors"

Comment: You should also report the precise error, and the line.  One problem with your code:    `"S6" & Rows.Count` -->`S61048576` which is not a valid address.  Perhaps you mean `"S" & Rows.Count`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I just changed it to "S" & Rows.Count throughout the code. This time I got a Compile Error: Next without For
Line 9

Comment: That's because you are trying to break up your `For...Next` with the `If...Then...Else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this differently.

Given:

- The cell to be modified will be the cell under a cell that contains `CPT`

  - in the algorithm below, we look for `CPT` all caps and only that contents.  Easily modified if that is not the case.
- Since you write " a five digit code", we need only extract the first five characters.
- IF you might have some cells that contain `CPT` where the cell underneath does not contain a CPT code, then we'd also have to check the contents of the cell beneath to see if it looked like a CPT code.

So we just use the `Range.Find` method:

```
Sub CPT()
    Dim WS As Worksheet, R As Range, C As Range
    Dim sfirstAddress As String

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet4")
With WS.Cells
    Set R = .Find(what:="CPT", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=True)
    If Not R Is Nothing Then
        sfirstAddress = R.Address
        Set C = R.Offset(1, 0)
        C.Value = Left(C.Value, 5)

        Do
            Set R = .FindNext(R)
            If Not R.Address = sfirstAddress Then
                Set C = R.Offset(1, 0)
                C.Value = Left(C.Value, 5)
            End If
        Loop Until R.Address = sfirstAddress
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

If this sequence is guaranteed to only be in Column `S`, we can change

```
With WS.Cells
```

**to**   `With WS.Columns(19).Cells`

and that might speed things up a bit.

You may also speed things up by adding turning off ScreenUpdating and Calculation while this runs.

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so so so so so much!!! It worked perfectly! I have been working on this (just this one issue in the code) for 2 days. I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: So my boss changed it up, she needs all text after the first 5 characters to be moved to another cell in column X. Is that even possible?

Comment: If you understand how the above algorithm is working, it should be a trivial change, involving string functions (probably `Mid`) and the `.Offset` property.  So first, go through the code step-by-step and make sure you understand each line.  Post back if you don't understand something. VBA Help will be useful, also.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error will occur here:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("S6" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Text
```

Because you're trying to retrieve text from the last used range starting `.End(xlUp)` at `Range("S61048576")`, which is roughly 58 times the row limit in Excel. You might change `Range("S6" & Rows.Count)` to `Range("S" & Rows.Count)`

Your second error will occur here:

```
LR = Range("S6" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Which will be the same error.

The third error will occur here:

```
For i = 1 To LR
    If InStr(1, celltxt, "CPT") Then
Next i
```

You cannot nest half of an `If-End If` block in a `For-Next` loop, or vice-versa and you've done both. If you want to iterate and perform an `If-End If` each iteration, you need to contain the `If-End If` within the `For-Next` like

```
For i = 1 To LR
    If InStr(1, celltxt, "CPT") Then
    'Is the purpose here to do nothing???
    Else
        With Range("S" & i)
            .Value = Left(.Value, InStr(.Value, " "))
        End With
    End If
Next i
```

**EDIT:**

For technical accuracy, your first error would actually be your broken up `For-Next` and `If-End If`, as you wouldn't even be able to compile to execute the code to run into the other two errors.

Comment: I have corrected the "S6" problem. 
For the line -- If Instr(1, celltxt, "CPT" Then
i am trying to tell the code that if the cell contains the word "CPT" to do nothing and move on to the next cell.

Comment: Then just test for `If InStr(1, celltxt, "CPT") > 0 Then` and remove the `Else` entirely.
InStr will return 0 if it finds nothing in the string.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the Mid function in the worksheet.
As I understood from your question that you need to separate numbers and put them in other cells, is this true?
To do this, you can write this function in cell R6 like this
=Mid(S6,1,5)
Then press enter and drag the function down and you will find that all the cells containing numbers and texts have been retained numbers in them

Comment: No the cells with the numbers and text need to only contain the numbers.
So the end result I am looking for is EX: Row 6 will have "CPT" and Row 7 will have only "99217" the rest of the text in Row 7 can be removed altogether.

Comment: @Hal I tried this function as the way you want it to be and the result is exactly what you want to reach , the value in S6 cell will remain "CPT" and the value in S7 cell will be "99217" but the result in the cell which you write function in it